# How to move a Component to center in react in mobile screen

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a react project, In that I have one parent component that is App.js for that App.js, Iconcircle.js is a child component.

Now for Iconcircle.js, Reusableicons.js is a child component. In Reusableicons.j's component I created an icon and I am planning to reuse it by using props in Iconcircle component.

Everything is working fine, but on mobile screen I am not able to move the icon component to the center.

Help me to overcome this

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Iconcircle from './Iconcircle/Iconcircle';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-12'>
          <Iconcircle></Iconcircle>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is Iconcircle.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './Iconcircle.css';
import Reusableicons from '../Reusableicons/Reusableicons';

export default function Iconcircle() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Reusableicons></Reusableicons>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is Reusableicons.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './Reusableicons.css';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faUser } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'


export default function Reusableicons() {
    return(
        <div className='user'>
            <FontAwesomeIcon className='commoniconstyle' icon={faUser} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

This Reusableicons.css

```
.user {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #263bd6;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #78ceff;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 115px;
    justify-content: center;
}

.commoniconstyle {
    font-size: 48px;
    color: white;
}
```

If I am not clear with my doubt, please put a comment.

Answer (score 0):

1.) The parent of `.user` has to have `display: flex` set in order to use flexbox properties. It's not clear if you set that already.

2.) It looks like you're using flexbox to center the element. Which would normally work fine. But if you're going that route, replace `vertical-align` with `align-items: center`, that is the flexbox way of centering along your 2nd axis

Comment: Hi @adamz4008 I tried what you said but its not working.